# android capture intruder video from lockscreen

Tags: android, lockscreen, device-admin, android-video-record

I am working on a project named as Anti-Theft android app. There are two tasks one is to capture intruder picture and the second is to capture intruder video for 5 to 10 seconds (on 3 wrong password attempts). The take picture method is working fine, but the takeVideo() method is not working for me. It says Error: -22.

Android Version: 9
Target SDK 33
Min SDK 24

Calling takeVideo() method from onPasswordFailed method.

Code:

```
 void takeVideo(int seconds) {
        backgroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                camera = null;
                mediaRecorder = null;
                SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(10);

                try {
                    camera = Camera.open(0);
                    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

                    camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
                    camera.startPreview();

                    // Set the audio source (e.g., MIC) before setting the audio encoder
                    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

                    // Set the video source and other media recorder settings
                    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
                    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
                    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
//                    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10 * 1000);

                    // Set the audio encoder
                    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

                    // Set the output file path for the video
                    String fileName = "video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
                    String directoryName = "AtexAntiTheft";
                    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), directoryName);

                    if (!directory.exists()) {
                        directory.mkdirs(); // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
                    }

                    File videoFile = new File(directory, fileName);

                    // Set the output file path for the video
                    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFile.getPath());

                    // Prepare and start recording with some delay (e.g., 1000ms)
                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.prepare();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);  // Add a delay to allow initialization
                        mediaRecorder.start();

                        // Record video for the specified duration
                        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e("Debug 1", "Error: "+e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        // Stop and release media recorder
                        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
                            try {
                                mediaRecorder.stop();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("Debug 2","Error: "+ e.getMessage());
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            mediaRecorder.reset();
                            mediaRecorder.release();
                        }

                        // Release the camera after recording the video successfully
                        if (camera != null) {
                            camera.stopPreview();
                            camera.release();
                        }

                        // Invoke the callback with the video file path
                        if (videoTakenCallback != null) {
                            videoTakenCallback.onVideoTaken(videoFile.getPath());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Debug 3", "Error: "+e.getMessage());
                    // Handle any exceptions and release resources
                    if (camera != null) {
                        camera.release();
                    }
                    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
                        mediaRecorder.reset();
                        mediaRecorder.release();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Screenshot of Logcat:
[image]

I have tried searching for the solutions, but nothing worked for me. and I am expecting to capture the intruder's short videos from lock screen.